# How to install and setup react-native-bootsplash for an expo app?

Tags: expo, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm facing issues with trying to get the FCM notification that openned the app with methods such as "messaging().getInitialNotification()" and "await messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {})" as they return null. I found that [react-native-bootsplash](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash) might fix the issue if you are using [react-native-splash-screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen), however, in my case I'm using the [expo splash screen](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/) package. In short, does anyone know how to download [react-native-bootsplash](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash) in an expo app? or did any face similar issue where you cannot get the initial notification? Really apreciate the help!!

I tried FCM functions such as "messaging().getInitialNotification()" and "await messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {})" but they returned nothing.